# Migrating windows project to VS 2017 with third party libraries

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, dependency-walker

I have a solution of about 10 projects, a mixture of c# and C++ which were built using VS 10 as DLLs and run with VC++ redist 10.
It uses various third-party libraries such as protobuf, gtest, openssl etc all built with vs 10 toolsets. And hence the application used to run smoothly loading these library dlls at runtime.

Now I had to upgrade the project and build the solution in VS 17 i.e. toolset 15.0. I have built all the projects and third-party libraries as well.

But I am using this one third-party Microsoft SCOM SDK library which I am not able to build with toolset 15.0

And when I run my application it fails to load the base dll, the project dll itself(which in turn links to Microsoft scom SDK dll).

dependency walker shows that the project's dll still depends on some vc++ 10 libraries despite building it with latest toolset 15.0 for vs2017.

When doing the migration, do we really have to rebuild each and every dependent dll including third-party dlls which are linked at run time?

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Does the dependency walker show the dependent libraries of the only the mentioned dll or also all the dlls recursively which it depends?
3. Is there are any alternative way in handling this?

Comment: If the third party libraries are designed so that resources allocated in them is also freed in them, then you may not have to recompile them.

Comment: If any of the library dependencies depend on VC++ 10 redist then your executable automatically becomes dependent on VC++ 10 redist. So yes, it would be a good idea to recompile all the dependencies for which you have a source code. Recompilation is mandatory if dependency uses C++ interface. Also note that you can continue using old toolset with newer visual studio.